# Retrieve values that are outside the context

Tags: c#, winforms

I dynamically create controls and I'd like to be able to use them outside of the context.

For example a dynamically created label :

```
i = 0;

while (readerBE.Read())
{
    Label labelBE = new Label();
    labelBE.Name = "labelBE" + i;
    labelBE.Text = readerBE["codeArticleComposant"].ToString();
    labelBE.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    labelBE.Click += new EventHandler(this.labelBE_Click);

    i++;
}
```

And when I try to use the `OnClick` event to retrieve a value like this :

```
private void labelBE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(labelBE.Text);
}
```

`labelBE` does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the `sender` argument:

```
private void labelBE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label labelBE = (Label) sender;
    Console.WriteLine(labelBE.Text);
}
```

But one thing, you have a `while`-loop and you always create this `Label` and you never add it to any container control (like `GroupBox`, `Panel` or `Form`). So you would never create multiple and either the `while`-loop is  wrong and should be replaced with an `if` or you should add the labels to a collection or parent control (well, you should do that anyway).

Comment: I do put the created Controls in a panel, I just didn't mention it in my post as I thought it was not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sender` object that generated the click :

```
private void labelBE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((Label)sender).Text);
}
```

However I suggest you read more about [Variable scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

Your problem is that you create a variable inside a method, so this variable is no more accessible once you leave it.